# Getting the position of the mouse or gesture during a Drag and Drop in .Net MAUI

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop, maui, gesture-recognition

Is it possible to get the position of the mouse or the finger during a Drag and Drop, using .Net MAUI?

Using the GestureRecognizers, I can use the DropGestureRecognizer to receive the DragOver event or the Drop event inside a view/control.  But I cannot find any way to get the position of the mouse or the finger during those events!

PointerGestureRecognizer are not fired during a Drag and Drop process.

I need this information to allow a Drop only in a small region of my GraphicsView.

I would expect the DragEventArgs to have a GetPosition method!

Comment: Not yet supported in MAUI. Discussed in [Mouse hover detection in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73088203/mouse-hover-detection-in-net-maui).: *"All requests for "desktop" style control of keyboard and mouse have been consolidated under [Maui issue: Desktop platforms: Mouse and Keyboard](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3739)."*