# How can I get the position where the user dropped the item? C# .NET Maui

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm new in .NET Maui and I was working on an application which needs to get the absolute location of the dropped item with the `DropGestureRecognizer` and until now I can't get it.

I've read thousands of docs of microsoft, stackoverflow, and more but they simply doesn't answer what I'm looking for so I decided to make a question myself.

How can I get the absolute location of the dropped item in .Net MAUI?

Any help is considered, thank you in advance.

EDIT: Also, if it's not implemented since .NET Maui is so new, just tell me.

Comment: You should show some code instead of simply explaining what you have tried or need to achieve as it will make it easier to understand the problem and  find an appropriate solution.

Comment: They are referring to Maui's lack of any way to get mouse/finger location during or after a drag & drop. See my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/q/74827486/199364, which links to the open proposal. (If you look at Maui source code, I think you'll see that it is a black box with no easy fix for this. Someone needs to completely rewrite drag & drop for each platform.) But that probably is much easier AFTER there is an implementation of "global mouse" handling a la Windows API.

Comment: It's not supported now. See this issue: [Support to get drag and drop position from DragEventArgs #2793](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2793)