# Can we design a star path that is hoverable and clickable in .NET MAUI and XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I'm learning .NET MAUI and XAML. How to create a star path (it could be any path, open or closed) such that:

- When the mouse is outside the path, it does nothing.
- When the mouse hovers the path, the star changes color.
- The path is clickable only when it is hovered.
- The path can be animated, such as transform a star into a ring.

I tried and read a few things on how to do it:

- Maui graphics: It is the first place I looked, but the path is "stuck" in a canvas. It makes it difficult to interact directly with the path. Although, for animation it would have been good.
- In the case of closed path, I look for using the Border control, but I did not find a way to make the border follow a weird path.
- I also look at the PointerOver Visual states of Views and it does not work very well for my problem. When the mouse enters the "sandbox or square area" where the path is drawn, the path changes color, even if the mouse does not hover directly the path.

If you know SVG in HTML and CSS, it possible adding only this CSS:

```
path: hover {
    fill: red;
}
```

I also read the answers to that question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73088203/mouse-hover-detection-in-net-maui](https://www.stackoverflow.com/). Since it is a fast evolving technology and there is a new release [https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/whats-new/dotnet-7.md#new-functionality](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) that included PointerGestureRecognizer and PointerOver, I decided to ask my question while specifying that I want the "Hover" to be precise and that the path can be animated if I want to.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Because Maui is a *cross-platform* UI, AND maps to *native* controls, it tends to be limited to functionality that can *easily* be implemented on *all* platforms. I doubt you'll be able to do this with Maui standard controls.

Comment: Just an idea. If you fill the interior of the path with multiple smaller (transparent or with the same color) controls maybe it will work for you with some additional effort.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! With the cross-platform objective in mind, I completely understand the limitation here. Weird control design might not be practical for user experience. Also, I think filling the interior with a smaller control would work for closed path. One issue I found difficult to "correct", is that the path is in a box. If my path is a simple diagonal, it creates a rectangle that contain the path and as I understand it, the view is the rectangle and not the diagonal. Thank you for your time! I'll focus my learning of more basic stuff.