# Getting the position of the mouse or gesture during a Drag and Drop in .Net MAUI Or the last position of mouse in the drop events

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui, maui-windows

In Maui Dotnet, I can't find any way to get the mouse or finger position during these Drag & Drop events! Or the last position of the mouse when the drop event is completed

I need this to get the mouse or finger position in the drag and drop events using maui Dotnet

Comment: Isn't that what you want : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/pointer?view=net-maui-7.0#get-the-gesture-position ?

Comment: No, I need to recover the position of the foam or the finger. Even I added a PointerMoved event which retrieves the mouse or finger position to drop element but this event is disabled during drag drop event.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Maui yet. You can check this answer about [Mouse hover detection in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73088203/mouse-hover-detection-in-net-maui).

They made a comment about the requests for control of keyboard and mouse in this thread [Desktop platforms: Mouse and Keyboard classes or DependencyServices](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3739).