# XAML MAUI - Adding a tooltip to a FlyoutItem

Tags: xaml, tooltip, maui, flyout

I have the follow code snippet:

```
<Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" x:Key="HomeFlyout">
    <Setter Property="FlyoutIcon" Value="tab_home.png" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger TargetType="FlyoutItem"
             Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger TargetType="FlyoutItem"
             Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FlyoutIcon" Value="tab_home_on.png" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Currently, this works fine, however, I'd like to add a simple tooltip to it.

Is this possible and how can it be done?

Comment: Just to clarify. What you mean when say "Tooltip"? I'm trying but I cant imagin how classic tooltip behavior can be implemented on mobile devices. There is no mouse poiter on most of it.

Comment: If you want to use the mouse hover to achieve the effect, you can check the [Mouse hover detection in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73088203/mouse-hover-detection-in-net-maui).

Comment: @IvanKozlov I just want some sort of mouse hover effect, doesn't necessarily have to be tooltip

Comment: @AdamGong I provided the link which people has made some comments indicated that the mouse hover effect can not be achieved by now.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT so can it be said MAU XAML no longer supports a tooltip/mouse over feature ?

Comment: No, Mouse hover detection in .NET MAUI has been put into a backlog and it will be considered in the future. But it is not available for now.